# Modify VB.net SQL search to use pattern

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

The code below  works great, and I need it to do more :).  It is for vb.net 2008 with access database.
At the moment it matches based on paramValue, and needs an exact match.
How can I change it to look for a pattern instead??  For example I want anything that contains the text "Fizz" and then "Bom".
--And PLEASE share any link where I can learn about this blend of SQL+access+vb.net.
Thank you!  Steve

```
Dim table As New DataTable(tableName)
table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Using connection As New OdbcConnection(ConnectionString)
    connection.Open()

    Dim query As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}] WHERE [{1}] = ?", _
                                        tableName, _
                                        paramName)
    Dim selectCommand As New OdbcCommand(query, connection)
    selectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OdbcParameter("@" & paramName, paramValue))

    Dim adapter As New OdbcDataAdapter(selectCommand)
    adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Mapped)
    adapter.Fill(table)
End Using

Return table
```

Comment: Beware your code is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: @user414564 You should vote up and / or accept answers that are useful to you, because it helps both the person answering and anyone who finds this question in the future.

Comment: Thanks.  LOL, I dont have enough rep to vote up, and dont know how to accept an answer.  Will learn how now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference link : [HERE](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread329296.html)

```
Dim SelectQry = "SELECT * FROM [{0}] WHERE [{1}] like '%" & _
                    strYourSearchValue & " %'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LIKE operator to do that.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Name LIKE '%Fizz%' AND Name LIKE '%Bom%'
```